# Huge placeholder for pictures outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to implement newsletters and I've inserted some pictures.

If I don't download the header-picture in the newsletter, the placeholder is just huge:

[image]

It works great on Gmail, outlook mobile but not on outlook desktop.

My code for the newsletter is the one provided below. The picture that makes problems is the one with alt="header".

Don't be confused why there's "height" set for so many elements. It was to test if anything affects the blocked picture but it doesn't.

```
<table id="header" width="100%" height="250px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="height:110px">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" height="110px" style="position:relative;height:110px;Background-color:#040C2C">
            <a href="{$baseUrl}/{$lng}" style="height:110px">
                <img style="width:100%; height:110px" height="110px" width="100%" src="{$baseUrl}{$SkinPath}/images/header_receipt.png" alt="header"></img>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;padding:0; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <xsl:value-of select="aspdnsf:ReceiptTopic('ReceiptHeader', $OrderNumber)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the width and height attributes (height=, width=), you don't put the units in there for px.

Also, to work out the proportions, with width attribute needs to be a pixel value.

So try:

`<img style="width:100%; height:110px" height="110" width="600" src="{$baseUrl}{$SkinPath}/images/header_receipt.png" alt="header">`

I also removed `</img>` as that's not a thing for the `<img>` tag, it self-closes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, sadly it didn't fix the problem

Comment: @SomeDumbQuestions Okay I've updated it and checked it this time. Seems needed a pixel value for width too.

Comment: Note that width="600" will work for Outlook, but you *can* still have widht:100% in the style attribute, and that will be used for everything else.

Comment: Thanks man, helped me alot it finally worked!